# Postgres session variables not working inside a function

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, session

I am setting a session variable inside a postgres function and the values are not getting set.
Any help is most appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I am using "PostgreSQL 10.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit"

My code is as follows:
The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_rp_vals(iv_rp_company varchar, iv_rp_portfolio varchar)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$

DECLARE

l_retval integer;

BEGIN

    l_retval := 1;

    RAISE NOTICE '1.iv_rp_company: >>> %', iv_rp_company;
    RAISE NOTICE '2.iv_rp_portfolio: >>> %', iv_rp_portfolio;

    --set the session variable
    set rp.company   = iv_rp_company;
    set rp.portfolio = iv_rp_portfolio;

    RETURN l_retval;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN 9;
    END;

$function$
;
```

The function call:

```
SELECT set_rp_vals(iv_rp_company := 'COMPAN',iv_rp_portfolio := 'PORTOF');
```

--Retrieving the session variables:

```
select 
current_setting('rp.company') as company,
current_setting('rp.portfolio') as portfolio;
```

[The value returned by the above query:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtRcU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `set_config()` function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_rp_vals(iv_rp_company varchar, iv_rp_portfolio varchar)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$

DECLARE

l_retval integer;

BEGIN

    l_retval := 1;

    RAISE NOTICE '1.iv_rp_company: >>> %', iv_rp_company;
    RAISE NOTICE '2.iv_rp_portfolio: >>> %', iv_rp_portfolio;

    --set the session variable
    perform set_config('rp.company', iv_rp_company, false);
    perform set_config('rp.portfolio', iv_rp_portfolio, false);

    RETURN l_retval;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN 9;
    END;

$function$
;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Execute with your values:

```
SELECT set_rp_vals(iv_rp_company := 'COMPAN',iv_rp_portfolio := 'PORTOF');            

NOTICE:  1.iv_rp_company: >>> COMPAN
NOTICE:  2.iv_rp_portfolio: >>> PORTOF
┌─────────────┐
│ set_rp_vals │
├─────────────┤
│           1 │
└─────────────┘
(1 row)

select                                                                                
current_setting('rp.company') as company,
current_setting('rp.portfolio') as portfolio;

┌─────────┬───────────┐
│ company │ portfolio │
├─────────┼───────────┤
│ COMPAN  │ PORTOF    │
└─────────┴───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Mike Thanks a lot. Your code works. I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks a lot again.